# c# convert datagridview id to collection names

Tags: c#, enums

I'm having problems with a datagridview. I'm trying to export the row selection of datagridview1 in a array to be used in a chart in the same solution. I need to convert those id's to the actual collection name. I tried with a enum list to convert the id to the collection name, but compiler gives me a error so in the end I used a case switch. Is enum the correct way to go to convert an id to a collection name or should I follow a different road?

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pen, position1, position2(Enum.GetName(typeof(collectioname),idofcollectioname), positionx2, positiony2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question but,

> I need to convert those id's to the actual collection name

If you mean by `Id` some value that can be **one** of **Limited Set** of values, the answer is **YES**, you can use an `Enum`.

But if the `Id` something else, the answer is **NO**, you can't use it.

Comment: by id i mean the id that is associated to the values in the enum series....like:   

     (id, value)
1, value1
2, value2|
3, value3

Comment: So its some value that can be one of Limited Set of values.